# What do I need to install a Visual Studio 2010 (sln)-compatible Build Agent in TeamCity?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, teamcity, build-agent

I seem to be unable to install a build agent on our TeamCity 5.1.2 build server that is compatible with a VS2010 (sln) build configuration.

Under "Build Runners", the following runners are listed:

> **Ant:** Runner for Ant build.xml files
>   **Duplicates finder (.NET):** C# and VB duplicate code finder
>   **Command Line:** Simple command execution

And under "Compatible configurations", the project I've configured to build with the Visual Studio 2010 (sln) build runner is listed under "Incompatible configurations".

To install the build agent, I'm simply running the .msi installation package, but it seems the default settings are not good enough. The build server machine has Visual Web Developer Express 2010 as well as .NET versions 2.0-4.0 installed, but no full version of VS. Do I need anything more?

(I have no experience whatsoever of building with msbuild scripts, so if I can I want to avoid having to do that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

Install the Windows SDK from Microsoft. Right now, the [latest version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b) is 7.1.

Note that since I just suddenly noticed that it worked, I don't know for certain that this is what did it - it might me completely irrelevant, but this is the only thing in my configuration I changed that I think could be relevant.

Comment: Yes, installing the Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4.0 is the thing to do. This gives you all the additional build targets you need.

Answer (score 3):

TeamCity build agent does not detect .NET 4.0 Client Profile as dotNetFramework4.0. Check you have full .NET Framework 4.0 installed.

Another reason of that is build agent has corrupted plugins. To fix it:
- stop agent
- remove /plugins, /system, /tools folders
- start agent
- wait till agent autoupgrade (agent service may be shown as stopped, just wait)