# TeamCity Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configurationn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, teamcity

I'm trying to set up continuous integration at my current place of work. It's not something I've done before so I'm fairly certain that there will be a few steps I've not done or things I'm un-aware of.

I installed TeamCity Professional 7.1.3 on a build server (Windows Server 2008 R2). I've created a simple .NET application that has no database connections and only three NUnit tests. This app uses .NET framework 4.

I set up a build step using NUnit and received a number of errors but I've now resolved them, basically by installing the .NET framework on the build server.

I'm now adding an extra step using Visual Studio but TeamCity now displays the warning 'No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration'.

This question looks similar to mine:
[What do I need to install a Visual Studio 2010 (sln)-compatible Build Agent in TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179921/what-do-i-need-to-install-a-visual-studio-2010-sln-compatible-build-agent-in-t)  and it helped me solve the problems I had with NUnit but not for this current problem.

Is there something I've missed during my set-up? If I'm building and running tests with NUnit do I need to bother with this second step?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you attempting to set up a build agent on another server?  (In case you're not familiar with the terminology: A 'build agent' is the process that does all the build work, as opposed to the 'build server,' whose job it is to monitor and farm out build jobs to the agents.  These processes *can* run on the same server instance, but typically don't.)

Comment: Check the 'Compatible Agents' tab on the build configuration, it'll usually tell you why each build agents doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: @John Hoerr. Everything is on the same server.

Comment: @JonathonRossi. It says 'Unmet requirements:DotNetFramework4.0_x86 exists'. I installed the .NET Framework earlier, which solved my problems with NUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed the full framework, correct -- not just the client pieces?  Here's a [TeamCity forum post](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/311239) on how to resolve the `Unmet requirements:DotNetFramework4.0_x86 exists` compatibility error when you've previously installed the framework.

Comment: Thanks John. That worked for me. I saw that link (or one very similar) earlier when I was having problems with NUnit but I think I would have needed to have installed the Net Framework on the server as well.