# Team city (build runner requirement)

Tags: teamcity-7.0

I have recently installed **TeamCity** for continuous integration and I am at a point before anything commited in SVN gets into queue in **TeamCity**.

Researching a bit, I found that I need an `Agent` to build. Now I have created an agent but I still get `Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration. Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration requirements.` error when I try to build my project.

I went into my Agents page , my newly created agent is still under the `incompatible agents` list with `Unmet requirements: DotNetFramework4.0_x86 exists` (I think which means I need this DOtNetFramework installed on my server) and I can't delete this requirement so I suppose this needed to be added considering my server is `Windows Server 2008 R2`.

I have tried installing `Microsoft .NET Framework 4` but that didn't help.

Can anyone please help in fixing this requirement error please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you restart the agent service since you installed the .net framework?

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden: restarting worked but now its struck on same error. History is that i started integrating this TeamCity in Nov last year but got busy in some other project. In a meantime, every commit we did got queued in TeamCity, today when i actually got it working. all the builds failed with same error. This looks like some setting in TeamCity being messed by me.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5316474

Comment: tried that and it didnt help, i just get this feeling its something to do with 'Execute step' question which has been set as 'Only if previous steps were successful' (which is selecetd by default)

Comment: Have uninstalled TeamCity from server and will now try to do everything again from scratch.

Comment: Please have a try for re-installing Windows SDK as it is mentioned in the answer for [What do I need to install a Visual Studio 2010 (sln)-compatible Build Agent in TeamCity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179921/what-do-i-need-to-install-a-visual-studio-2010-sln-compatible-build-agent-in-t). It says that "This gives you all the additional build targets you need".

Comment: The link provided by James Woolfenden above solved it for me.  The last comment in that link mentions that the service account has to have permissions to download the plugins under the TeamCity installation path.  Everything started working for us once we put our build-account user in a group with sufficient access permissions.

Answer (score 7):

In your TeamCity Build Agents list select one of your build agent, open the tab **'Agent Parameters**' and click subtab of 'Configuration Parameters'.

Check whether the following configurations are having same values of as below (with assumption that you have installed .NET 4.0 in drive C: in you TeamCity build agent):

```
DotNetFramework4.0_x86 - 4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.0_x86_Path - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

If it is similar or same, then open the TeamCity Build Configuration you have setup and open the 'Settings' tab in that edit the '**Agent Requirements**' section.
In that please check whether you have conditions set for values of config parameters `DotNetFramework4.0_x86` and `DotNetFramework4.0_x86_Path` and if it is present, ensure that those are matching with the values posted above.

Once these values are matching, then this compatibility issue will not pop up anymore.

Comment: But what if I don't have that configuration under tab 'Agent Parameters' and subtab of 'Configuration Parameters'? how can I delete undeletable 'Agent Requirements' section.?

Comment: @dollar8, If you have administration rights in your TeamCity application you should be easily able to delete the items under 'Agent Requirements'. But not possible to delete the 'Agent Requirements' section itself completely.